# Crontab syntax - Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, command

I used the following command in crontab to execute these three commands in a a row every week:

```
0 0 * * 6 docker export dfdf > backup.tar && python gdrive-upload/upload.py -i backup.tar -o $(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%I-%M-%p")-backup.tar -f backup && rm backup.tar
```

However, syslog shows the following:

```
Feb 25 17:36:30 xxx cron[3314]: Error: bad hour; while reading crontab for user root  
Feb 25 17:36:30 xxx cron[3314]: (root) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

The problem should be on the second command as I tried with first && third only and works fine.

```
python gdrive-upload/upload.py -i backup.tar -o backup.tar -f backup
```

I wonder why the command syntax is wrong (besides the %)? I have tried it in the command line and it works fine.

I am using ubuntu. Previously the `crontab` does not work so I deleted `/etc/environment` file.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @choroba Feb 25 17:36:30 xxx cron[3314]: Error: bad hour; while reading crontab for user root Feb 25 17:36:30 xxx cron[3314]: (root) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)

Comment: "bad hour" means the syntax of the time field is wrong, but `0` seems pretty OK for an hour. Are you sure you haven't included any non-printing characters?

Comment: to check for possibly invisible wrong characters you could use `od -c your_crontab_file`

Comment: `%` has special meaning in crontab it needs to be escaped.

Comment: Many thanks. But the problem seems more than that. I deleted the % symbol but the error msg still appears.

Comment: I guess the problem is on the second command - python gdrive-upload/upload.py -i backup.tar -o $(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%I-%M-%p")-backup.tar -f backup ,  would too many arg cause problems?